# Convolution of two Gaussian mixture model

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, gaussian, convolution, bayesian-probability

Suppose I have two independent random variables $X$, $Y$, each modeled by the Gaussian mixture model (GMM). That is,
$$
f(x)=\sum _{k=1}^K \pi _k \mathcal{N}\left(x|\mu _k,\sigma _k\right)
$$
$$
g(y)=\sum _{i=1}^N \lambda _i \mathcal{N}\left(y|\mu _i,\sigma _i\right)
$$
Now, I would like to know the PDF of another variable $Z$, where $Z=X+Y$.

Is there anyone who can write the explicit PDF of $Z$?

Answer (score 2):

The pdf of the sum $X+Y$ of independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ is the convolution of the pdf's of $X$ and $Y$. The convolution operation is bilinear. The convolution of Gaussian pdf's is Gaussian. So, letting $f_j(t):=\mathcal{N}(t\big|\mu_j,\sigma_j)$ and noting that $(f_k*f_i)(z):=\mathcal{N}\left(z\big|\mu_k+\mu_i,
\sqrt{\sigma_k^2+\sigma_i^2}\right)$, we find that the pdf $h$ of your $Z=X+Y$ is
$$
h=\Big(\sum _{k=1}^K \pi_k\, f_k\Big)
*\Big(\sum _{i=1}^N \lambda_i\, f_i\Big)
=\sum _{k=1}^K\sum _{i=1}^N \pi_k\lambda_i\, f_k*f_i
$$
and hence the pdf $h$ of your $Z=X+Y$ is also a Gaussian mixture given by
$$
h(z)=\sum _{k=1}^K\sum _{i=1}^N \pi_k\lambda_i\, \mathcal{N}\left(z\big|\mu_k+\mu_i,
\sqrt{\sigma_k^2+\sigma_i^2}\right).
$$

Comment: Thank you losif. Although I agree with the theory you posted, I don't think the pdf of Z is as easy as h(z).

Comment: @wuhanichina : So, you agree with the proof but don't think that what is proved is true? How can that be? Anyway, I have added some details, which may be helpful to you.